# Supervisor configured on elastic beanstalk ec2 is not listening to the queue on databas's jobs table

Tags: laravel, database, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

This is my comment

```
sudo php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work database --queue=database --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

But this does'nt let even write any logs to my laravel-queue.log(log file has enough permission).Why this may be